# cannot find amount of days until next birthday for the user input

Tags: javascript, datetime

#### Below will get the amount of days until the persons birthday, If the birthday has already been it will then give you the previous days of when your birthday was!

#### I'm Still wondering weather it's possible to calculate the amount of days until the next birthday, This would require going past december and keep on counting from january. I can't seem to get it right.

```
 //Getting birthday and month form form
 var birthdayMonth = document.getElementById('selMonth').value;
 var birthdayDay = document.getElementById('selDay').value;

//Parsing Birthday and month
birthdayMonth = parseInt(birthdayMonth);
birthdayDay = parseInt(birthdayDay);

    //setting date object
    today = new Date( );          // set today's date
    birthday = new Date( );      // set up the Birthday object
    birthday.setMonth(birthdayMonth);      // set birthday month to December
    birthday.setDate(birthdayDay);         // set birthday date to the 15th

if (today < birthday)
 {  //this gets days until next birthday - 
     diff = Math.abs(birthday.getTime( ) - today.getTime( ));
     diff = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
     alert('There are ' + diff + ' days until your birthday ');
  }
else
{ //This gets days since last birthday - 
    diff = Math.abs(today.getTime( ) - birthday.getTime( ));
    diff = Math.floor(diff / (1000*60*60*24));
    alert('It was ' + diff + ' days since your last birthday');

}
```

Comment: What is your question though?

Comment: Have tried logging the values of `birthdayMonth` and `birthdayDay` before you try to use them?

Comment: @winterblood I have a form where the users choose there birth date! I have tried many times to get the .value(which are numbers representing the specific date (eg: febuary(2))

Comment: Remember months are 0-indexed in Javascript (as in your setDate, Decemeber is 11), if you have February with a value of 2 in your HTML, you will have to decrement the birthdayMonth before using it.

Comment: Also remember that you are not setting the year in your code - if the birthday is less than  or equal to today's date, it will be trying to calculate off the entered date in 2014, and thus will not make it into the `if (today.getTime( ) < birthday.getTime( ))` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var birthdayMonth = document.getElementById('selMonth').value;
var birthdayDay = document.getElementById('selDay').value;

birthdayMonth = parseInt(birthdayMonth);
birthdayDay = parseInt(birthdayDay);

    today = new Date( );          // set today's date
    birthday = new Date( );      // set up the Birthday object
    birthday.setMonth(birthdayMonth-1);      // set birthday month to December
    birthday.setDate(birthdayDay);         // set birthday date to the 15th

if (today < birthday)
 {  
     diff = Math.abs(birthday.getTime( ) - today.getTime( ));
     diff = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
     alert('There are ' + diff + ' days until ' + (birthdayMonth)+ ' ' + birthdayDay);
  }
else
{
    alert("B'day has passed!");
}
```

[And here's the JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/df0x3bzr/)

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks! I uploaded an answer with an updated version. Im not sure if you would know how to figure out my question on it!

Comment: Don't add answers yourself. Update your question with what you tried instead. And, remember to vote if an answer was useful. I'll have a look at your other issue now.

Comment: And, don't delete your original question. Just add the update at the bottom of your question with a heading Update 1, Update 2 etc :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Here I have completed the task I was trying to do... This will ***check how many days it was since there last birthday***. This will ***check how many days until there next birthday***. It will also ***check if todays the users birthday***.

Thanks everyone for helping me get to this conclusion. With your help I was able to complete it! I hope this helps anyone trying to do something similar.

```
var output = '';
        var birthdayMonth = document.getElementById('selMonth').value;
        var birthdayDay = document.getElementById('selDay').value;
        
        birthdayMonth = parseInt(birthdayMonth);
        birthdayDay = parseInt(birthdayDay);
        
        //Date Objects
            today = new Date( );          // set today's date
            birthday = new Date( );      // Birthday object setup e.g(birthday.getTime());
        
            birthday.setMonth(birthdayMonth);      // set birthday month (userInput)
            birthday.setDate(birthdayDay);         // set birthday date (userInput)
        
        //Check if todays the users Birthday
        if(birthday.valueOf() == today.valueOf()){
            sweetAlert("Happy birthday!");  
        }
        
        //Until Next Birthday
        if (today > birthday)
        {
        // If the birthday is passed it will calculate how long until it comes next, even if it's next year.
            birthday.setYear(today.getFullYear() + 1); // Set Year = current year + 1
            diff = Math.abs(birthday.getTime( ) - today.getTime( ));
            diff = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
            //alert('There are ' + diff + ' days until your birthday'/*Add this for actual date -> birthday*/); alerting how many days
            output += 'There are ' + diff + ' days until birthday'/*Add this for actual date -> birthday <- */;
        }
        
        //Days since last birthday! e.g(may 20 till today(oct 29))
            birthday.setYear(today.getFullYear()); // Set year is normal. (no +1)
            PRdiff = Math.abs(today.getTime( ) - birthday.getTime( ));
            PRdiff = Math.floor(PRdiff / (1000*60*60*24));
            //alert('It was ' + PRdiff + ' days since your last birthday');  Alerting how many days
            output += '<br />It was ' + PRdiff + ' since your last birthday';
            
            //Output it to the page
            document.getElementById('birthdayOutput').innerHTML = output;
```

Comment: Good work. So @ Stack Overflow (SO) you say thank you by accepting and voting for the answers that was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not setting the year if his birthday had gone past this year.

Let me say today is 28 October, All other birthday date > 28 && month > 10 will work.
But It will not work for the past month and past dates. So if the birth day already crossed in this year you should have to add 1 to the year so that it will check for next Birthday(ie. Next Year).

```
today = new Date( );          // set today's date
birthday = new Date( );      // set up the Birthday object
birthday.setMonth(11);      // set birthday month to December
birthday.setDate(22);         // set birthday date to the 15th
if (today.getTime( ) >= birthday.getTime( )) //Add current year+1 if birthday already reached for this year
{
   birthday.setYear(today.getYear()+1);
}
if (today.getTime( ) < birthday.getTime( ))
{  diff = birthday.getTime( ) - today.getTime( );
   diff = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
   document.write('There are ' + diff + ' days until ' + (birthdayMonth+1)+ ' ' + birthdayDay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer if you need to calculate dates to B'day irrespective of the year

```
var birthdayMonth = document.getElementById('selMonth').value;
var birthdayDay = document.getElementById('selDay').value;

birthdayMonth = parseInt(birthdayMonth);
birthdayDay = parseInt(birthdayDay);

    today = new Date( );          // set today's date
    birthday = new Date( );      // set up the Birthday objectbirthday.setDate(birthdayDay);

    birthday.setMonth(birthdayMonth-1);      // set birthday month to December
    birthday.setDate(birthdayDay);         // set birthday date to the 15th

if (today > birthday)
{
    // If the B'day is less than current day means you are refering to the next B'day
    birthday.setYear(today.getFullYear() + 1); // Set Year = current year + 1
}

diff = Math.abs(birthday.getTime( ) - today.getTime( ));
diff = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
alert('There are ' + diff + ' days until ' + birthday);
```

[And, here's the JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4a12jt8/1/)